# Java returns different source than my browser shows

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the contents of a page using the following code (android):

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
httpGet.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/536.28.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.3 Safari/536.28.10");
try {
  HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
  InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

  BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
  String s = "";
  while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(s);
  }

} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This works fine for sites like google, but the specific site I want to access (http://www.swimrankings.net/index.php?internalRequest=athleteLookup&athlete_lastname=jansen&athlete_clubId=273&athlete_gender=-1) returns a PHP error (`Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: Config::$defaultLanguage in C:\Data\htdocs\www.swimrankings.net\classes\BSLanguage.php on line 16`).

I do not get this error when viewing the site with my browser. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Thanks!

**NOTE**
I already tried using the built in java URLConnection. I also tried setting the headers to exactly the same as safari shows me it used to access the page, but to no avail.

Comment: It's a guess, but maybe the PHP script tries to determine your preferred language. You could try to emulate that as well by setting the `Accept-Language` to `nl-NL`.

Comment: This can be because, the source site may be using one of the request header which is being passed by the browser but DefaultHttpClient is not passing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @mthmulders for the fix! The problem was that *Accept-Language* was not defined, causing PHP to error. Setting this to a language ("en", "de", "fr") fixed the problem.

**Fixed Code**:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
httpGet.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/536.28.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.3 Safari/536.28.10");
httpGet.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en");
try {
  HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
  InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

  BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
  String s = "";
  while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(s);
  }

} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```